# How to determine who has the winning ticket in array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a ticket system. Each person has varying # of tickets.
For example:

```
person[0] = 50;
person[1] = 75;
person[2] = 81;
```

The person 0 owns tickets from 1-50,

The person 1 owns tickets from 51-126,

The person 2 owns tickets from 127-208

Then the draw happens and it generates random ticket using this formula:

```
totalTickets*(randomProcentage/100)
```

For example the formula gives me "52" ticket as a winner. I don't know how to find who has the winning ticket.

Comment: Who? checking if it's in the array is trivial, it's just `arr.indexOf(52)`, but how would that tell you who won?

Comment: I did try to make a for loop inside a while loop, but it didn't work out since the loop stops and the right value but not give me the winner.

Comment: which one is taken with 52?

Comment: The person 1 should win because he has tickets from 51 to 126

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all tickets have the same probability to be picked, you can use this:

```
Math.floor(Math.random() * numberOfTickets);
```

Where the result is the winning ticket.

```
var tickets = [52, 44, 33];
var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * tickets.length);
var winningTicket = tickets[index];
```

In reference to comments. The tickets array denotes the number of tickets each other has. Code below is a simple example to find the index of the winner:

```
var tickets = [52, 44, 33];

// Sum the number of tickets
var numberOfTickets = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < tickets.length; i++) {
    numberOfTickets += tickets[i];
}

// Draw random number from 0 ... numberOfTickets
var winningTicket = Math.floor(Math.random() * numberOfTickets);

// Loop the tickets and check if the accumulated sum is higher or equal
// compared to the winning ticket. If it is, then we have our winner
var winner = null;
var accumulativeSum = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < ticket.length; i++) {
    accumulativeSum += ticket[i];
    if (accumulativeSum >= winningTicket) {
        winner = i;
        break;
    }
}
```

Tickets: [10, 20, 30], winningTicket = 5. Winner = 0

Tickets: [10, 20, 30], winningTicket = 11. Winner = 1

Comment: Each ticket has the same probability, but some people have more and some have less that's the catch.

Comment: @TwitchClips Some people have more and some have less? As in one person can have more tickets? For simplicity, I would advice you to order the list of tickets in a one dimensional array, like I have done. If the tickets have an unique value you can using the winning ticket to find out which person owns that ticket afterwards.

Comment: @TwitchClips more and less what? Give examples of what you are trying to achieve!

Comment: I failed to show this correctly, but these are the # of tickets and now the ticket numbers, so each array length has diffrent chance to win.

Comment: @TwitchClips You can then loop through the list of tickets, sum the number of tickets and the loop list of tickets one more time afterwards to find the winner.

Comment: @TwitchClips See updated answer for example code of what I mean

Comment: Works like a charm ty so much !

Answer (score 0):

You could sum the count of tickets and loop until the sum is greater or equal to the given value.

```js
var ticket = [50, 75, 81],
    value = 52,
    index = 0,
    sum = 0;

ticket.some(function (a, i) {
    sum += a;
    index = i;
    return sum >= value;
});
    
console.log(index);
```